# Rake Tasks get executed one extra time each time Sidekiq worker is run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, sidekiq

I have a rails application that make use of `sidekiq` and `sidekiq-cron` to run some rake tasks on a schedule.

Here is a sample worker

```
def perform
  RailsApp::Application.load_tasks

  # generate output json
  Rake::Task["json:output_data"].execute

  # run r-script
  Rake::Task["r_script:generate_questions"].execute
end
```

And a sample task

```
task output_data: :environment do
  p "generating output data"
  unless Dir.exist?("vendor/r_script/data/output_json")
    FileUtils.mkdir_p("vendor/r_script/data/output_json")
  end
  unless Dir.exist?("vendor/r_script/data/input_json")
    FileUtils.mkdir_p("vendor/r_script/data/input_json")
  end
  Rake::Task["json:generate_master_json"].execute
  Rake::Task["json:generate_raters"].execute
  Rake::Task["json:generate_ratees"].execute
end
```

The first time I queue the worker using the cron tab in the sidekiq web interface, it works fine. "generate output data" prints once as expected. Every time I run it again, "generate output data" prints an extra time. For every nth time enqueuing the sidekiq job, it prints n times.

How do I prevent this from happening? Do I need to clear the tasks somehow?

Comment: How do you add worker to crontab first time?

Comment: a schedule.yml file, with a cron, class, and queue